# Tell node to use global modules

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Situation: I want to tell my node to use global modules if local not found.
my package.json works fine with local installed packages.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "browserify -t vueify -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] -e script/dev/main.js -o script/prod/build.js",
```

But I dont want to install every time my dev packages. 
So I've installed all of this dev packages globally.

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-r....and so on..... -g
```

But when I tried to `npm run build` from my local dir, my node yells on me - he cant find this modules localy.
So, how I can tell my node to use global modules instead?

Comment: Because `npm` is using `./node_modules/bin` [`PATH`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path) and tries to run your modules from this local bath in your project , and when you install your modules locally your `./node_modules/bin` folder will have all your scripts

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is - "how to tell node to use global modules if local not found?"